# How do I debug a URL in a route in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to use two variables in the URL for a Camel route.  If I hard code the values in the URL the route works.  If I make them dynamic using `${}` I get an error message saying `Input string was not in a correct format`.  Here's the code with my attempt to pull the values `id1` and `id2` from the headers:

```
  from(SOURCE)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
//  .to("http://restUrl:8090/content/json/13/630?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    .to("http://restUrl:8090/content/json/${in.header.id1}/${in.header.id2}?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    .process(processor);
```

I've verified that those values exist correctly in the header.  What am I doing wrong, and how would I see the value for the dynamically created URL?

Comment: If you print them do they have values? Something like `<log message="header 1 value: ${in.header.id1}" />` Or `<log message="headers: ${headers}" />`

Comment: you need to use `toD` for dynamic to.

Comment: Oh, Duh.  That was it.  Thanks Claus.  Is there a way to see the dynamically created URL?